# How can I save a frame of a mantaflow simulation and use it as a mesh?

Tags: particles, fluid-simulation, baking, timeline, mantaflow

So I’ve done a mantaflow fluid simulation, but I want only 1 frame of it and use it as a static object, is there a way to do that?

I’ve tried hitting the convert button but that’s converting every particle as its own object and my Blender gets really laggy as I have many thousand particles in there. I’ve also tried to convert them all into one object but my blender crashes every time.

I figured that I can delete all frames of the cache except the one that I want and make as many duplicates of it so it fits every frame of my timeline, which is not very convenient. Is there a better way to do that?

Comment: Can't you just pause the simulation, or select a frame manually, then right click the emitter object and select "convert to > mesh"?

Comment: If I do that the particles disappear.

Comment: Sorry, I was thinking FLIP, even though you specified mantaflow multiple times. I must be tired :( I'll look into it with mantaflow.

Comment: It's ok, thank you very much.